# how to get the first day of the first month of the current year in RPGLE

Tags: rpgle

dcl-s today date inz(*Sys) is  the current sytem date 
 How do i get the first day of the first month of the current year in this format 2017/01/01

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [the %SUBST built-in function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/bbsubd.htm).

```
date = d'1999-02-17';
time = t'01.23.45';
timestamp = z'1999-02-17-01.23.45.98765';

num = %subdt(date:*YEARS);
// num = 1999

num = %subdt(time:*MN);
// num = 23
```

Comment: How can i get the first day of the first month of the current year on my default date field example: current year (2007)/01/01

Comment: So the first day of the first month of any year is 1/1 right? all you need to retrieve is the year, then build the string. This answer tells you how to extract the year from a date. You should be able to figure out how to construct the date.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slick trick:

```
   dcl-proc BuildDate;
     dcl-pi *n date;
       pyear     int(5) const;
       pmonth    int(5) const;
       pday      int(5) const;
     end-pi;

     dcl-ds *n;
       dateds   date(*iso) inz(d'0001-01-01');
       year     zoned(4:0) pos(1);
       month    zoned(2:0) pos(6);
       day      zoned(2:0) pos(9);
     end-ds;

     year = pyear;
     month = pmonth;
     day = pday;

     test(e) dateds;
     if %error;
       reset dateds;
     endif;

     return dateds;
   end-proc;
```

Now all you need to do to construct a valid date given Day Month and Year is:

```
FirstDOY = BuildDate(%subdt(%date(): *Y): 1: 1);
```